# Process.Start on bat file displays a run/cancel dialogue

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I have an SSIS package using vb.net PROCESS.START on a BAT file in order to execute it.  However, it displays a user run/cancel dialogue.  That, obviously, won't work for automation purposes. How do I get rid of this?  I have other bat files that do not do this, I guess the location is the reason why I get this: `We can't verify who created this file, are you sure you want to run this file?`. But I need to run it from that location.

Comment: Could you post the current `.bat` script you're using?

Comment: Go to properties of your bat file, find "Advanced" and check "Run as administrator"

Comment: UnknownOctopus: Do you mean the code inside the bat file, or the vb.net code I'm using to execute the bat file?
T.S.:  I will try this - you mean this is actually expected to solve the problem permanently?  I've not heard of this. Will try in the AM, Arizona time.

Answer (score 0):

I added file:\SERVERIPDADDRESS to the internet options > security > intranet > sites > advanced list.

Don't like the solution, but will work for now.